# Undistort camera video based on homography to undistorted image

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, homography

Consider the following problem:

- I have the original image A saved as "A.png".
- Moreover, I also have camera video feed that shows (possibly with some perspective transformation) an image of A, denoted Va, with some level of radial distortion.
- I also have an homography from A to Va and its inverse.

How could I undistort Va? Note that I do not want to undo the perspective transformation, just remove the radial distortion from Va.

Example:

- I have a fully mapped and undistorted reference image (including real world size)
- an image from a video frame (left image)
- and an homography and its inverse between those two

In our use case, the left image would have radial distortion but we would like to remove it without applying a simple backprojection (this would create artifacts)

[image]

Comment: need to know intrinsic parameters to apply undistortion. They should be either documented by camera/lens manufacturer or determined by bundle adjustment based on some priori knowledge (e.g. curves in Va are actually straight lines) consider attaching example pictures

Comment: With the homography matrix can't I find out if straight lines are getting distorted during backprojection? I'll add an example image soonish.

Comment: @baci I added an example. The left image is undistorted but in our actual example the left image would be distorted.

Comment: please show representative data

Answer (score 0):

Undistortion is the process to transform a *distorted* image (e.g. image with a fisheye pattern) to *undistorted* version.

In this case your video frames do not suffer from distortion. And if you have already determined homography matrix, you need to apply [perspective transformation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87).

You might need to invert the homography matrix in case you need to invert the transformation direction.